# need to call powershell function .ps1 of remote repo from github actions workflow

Tags: powershell, function, github-actions, reusability, ps1

I have my powershell function that takes 2 parameters and returns a value in public repo `betech` branch `feature365` here:

https://github.com/knowyrtech/betech/blob/feature365/scripts/xml-functions.ps1

```
function Get-XMLKeyValue {
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $XmlPath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string] $Key
  )

  $value = (Select-Xml -LiteralPath $XmlPath -XPath "//setParameter[@name='$Key']").Node.Value
  Write-Output $value
}
```

In another public repo `actions_param`  I have github action workflow that needs to call the `xml-functions.ps1` function `Get-XMLKeyValue` and get back the return value:

https://github.com/knowyrtech/actions_param/blob/main/.github/workflows/main.yaml

```
name: main xml read

on:
  push:
    branches: main
    
jobs:

  extract_key_value:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Extract XML Key-Value
        id: extract-xml-value
        uses: ./betech/scripts/xml-functions.ps1@feature365
        with:
          xmlPath: ${{ env.XML_PATH }}
          key: ${{ env.KEY_NAME }}

      - name: Show Extracted Key-Value
        run: |
          echo "Extracted Key-Value: ${{ steps.extract-xml-value.outputs.value }}"
```

Running the action gets me the below error:

```
Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under 'D:\a\actions_param\actions_param\betech\scripts\xml-functions.ps1@feature365'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?
```

I'm not sure if we can call the ps1 file directly. If not how can I reuse the function to get me the values? I'm new to github actions. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Use an Alias : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/parameter-aliases?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3